# ”No trees grows/grow overnight”

Tags: phrases

1. No trees grows overnight.
2. No trees grow overnight.

Which one is correct?
I know this is a phrase but if it is not a phrase then according to grammar which one is right?

Comment: It's a sentence, not a phrase. 2, is correct, but you could also say "No tree grows overnight.

Comment: Can You Explain a little bit why both are correct?

Comment: Please don't write every word with a capital letter! @BillJ did _not_ say that both are correct - _trees grows_ is an incorrect use of the verb. A whole tree can't appear overnight, but trees _do_ in fact grow during the night, according to [this](https://www.chemistryviews.org/details/news/11307503/Why_Trees_Grow_at_Night/).

Comment: @KateBunting  But in my text book  "No  trees grows overnight" is right

Comment: Then your textbook is talking nonsense, or you have mis-read it. A tree **grows** - many trees **grow**.  As Bill says, _No tree (singular) grows overnight_ would be correct.

Comment: @KateBunting No Tree grows to the sky. ( is an idiom) and you are correct here. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your rule: match the forms of the noun and the verb following for number (that is singular or plural).

> **No [singular thing] [singular verb]**
>
> No tree grows overnight.
> No good deed goes unrewarded.
> No dog eats sawdust.

> **No [plural things] [plural verb]**
>
> No trees grow overnight.
> No good deeds go unrewarded.
> No dogs eat sawdust.